# Computer crashes and freezes a lot

Tags: windows-7

My computer crashes like it freezes sometimes but sometimes it jumps to a black/blue screen which I can do nothing about other than restart.
I tested if it has anything to do with the programs I normally run or with the ones I installed, but it's a long time I have the problem and I think it also happened in the beginning that I bought this computer.
To make sure, I normally run skype and [Spiral Knights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_Knights) and some animation softwares like Flash.

The specs are:

> Nvidia geforce gtx 560 evga
> Asus p8H67-m evo motherboard
> 16 gb ram Intel i7

What can I do about it? What issue is more probable to cause the problem?

This is the message I got after rebooting:

> a clock interrrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time intervall.
>
> Technical information:
> ***stop: 0x00000101 (0x00000000000000019,0x000000000000000000, 0xFFFFF880030F9180,0x0000000000000006)

Comment: We are going to need quite a bit more information. Do you get messages when you reboot saying what crashed?

Comment: @soandos: Yes, added to my question.

Comment: Any events in the event logs that might help us?

Comment: Is your processor overclocked? This post on Microsoft's website may help you: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/stop-0x00000101-a-clock-interrupt-was-not-received/fa4a75d5-9f76-42f3-879a-76c184320647?page=2

Answer (score 2):

According to a [post here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/stop-0x00000101-a-clock-interrupt-was-not-received/fa4a75d5-9f76-42f3-879a-76c184320647) power management software is to blame. You also might want to check if you are overclocking, and if so, reset it to normal.

Would also not hurt to make sure that you have the latest BOIS version and motherboard drivers.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, could you please elaborate a bit as I'm not familiar with the terms you used. power management is a software, right? and that's the problem? I don't know how to disable it as the answer there mentioned.

Comment: Do you have any software that is not part of windows that is configuring your power settings? also, take a look at `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options`

Comment: Isn't it something special for laptops?

Comment: The path might be different, but things like going to sleep, turning off HD, etc are common to both types

Comment: I can do nothing from control panel, everything seems right. But should I disable it from F8 menu at the start up?

Answer (score 1):

- Check your [Windows 7 power settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9090/learning-windows-7-manage-power-settings/) and try to set it to "High performance". Have a look if your BIOS has some power options, if yes, disable them. Do the same for any other power management tools you might have installed. If the problem persist, you can restore all the settings.
- Get some program to check your CPU temperature, e.g. [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/). For the GPU, the NVidia Control Panel should show it, though I'm not sure about it.
- Run [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to make sure your memory is fine

EDIT: After the update to your question showing the specific error, I think a problem with power management is most likely. Google found [this question at microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/stop-0x00000101-a-clock-interrupt-was-not-received/fa4a75d5-9f76-42f3-879a-76c184320647). The accepted answer is:

> I had this on my lenovo w701--it ended up being the power management
>   software--I disabled it and viola no more issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I didn't notice there's another answer!

Comment: @gigili Quick interject here. On the overclockers site, they are finding that specific C states (standby states) as allowable in the hardware bios are not "as stable"  If adjusting the OS power management to stay out of standby altogether is solving problems, Adjusting the allowable Cstates c2 c3 c5 c6 might solve it , and still allow for the system power mannagement. It can be easy to follow a "Guide" for specific boards, but I did not find one yet for that board.  A least and quick move, would be to test with only C2 &or C3 states , in the motherboard bios.